# URL redirection via cookie parsing

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to look at a portion of a cookie's value, and if it contains `'en_us'`, do one thing, and if it contains `'es_us'`, do another thing instead.

I've written up code that pulls the cookie, returns the cookie value, and then looks to see if the cookie value includes 'en_us'. But I feel like this code can be shortened, I just am struggling with how.

```
const getCookie = async (name) => {
  const cookie = await cookieStore.get(name);
  return cookie.value;
}
const cookieValue = await getCookie('foo');
const cookieEnglish = cookieValue.includes('en_us');
if(cookieEnglish) {
  redirect to A
} else { 
  redirect to B
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to shorten it? I mean you can do it like this:

```
if((await cookieStore.get(name))?.value.includes('en_us')) {
  redirect to A
} else { 
  redirect to B
};
```

But I would lean more towards:

```
const getCookie = async (name) => {
  return (await cookieStore.get(name))?.value
}

const isCookieEnglish = (cookie) => {
  return cookie.includes('en_us')
} 

const cookie = await getCookie('foo')
if(isCookieEnglish(cookie)) {
  redirect to A
} else { 
  redirect to B
};
```

Although this has a bug - if foo does not exist we predispose it is Spanish.